# Configuring sample webcontext with JOSSO+TOMCAT

Tags: tomcat, josso

Newbie to JOSSO. I have setup JOSSO with tomcat and the partnerapp seems to be working correctly. I have a 'sample' webapp which i'm trying to configure with JOSSO. The JOSSO login page correctly appears when i try to access the webapp however **after i login successfully i get the following exception**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Outbound relaying failed. No Principal found. Verify your SSO Agent Configuration!
    org.josso.tc60.agent.SSOAgentValve.invoke(SSOAgentValve.java:551)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have added partner-app entry to josso-agent-config.xml.

```
<agent:partner-app id="MySampleApp" context="/sample"/>
```

My web.xml looks like this

```
...
    <welcome-file-list id="WelcomeFileList">
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <!-- Sample Security Constraint -->
        <web-resource-collection>

            <!-- We're going to protect this resource and make it available only to users in "role1". -->
            <web-resource-name>protected-resources</web-resource-name>

            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>

        </web-resource-collection>

        <!-- NOTE: This role names will be retrieved by Josso using the proper identity store. -->
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>role1</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>

    </security-constraint>  

    <security-role >
        <description>Role 1</description>
        <role-name>role1</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>

        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>

        <form-login-config>
            <!--
            NOTE: This will redirect the user to the proper login page provided by JOSSO.
            -->
            <form-login-page>/login-redirect.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login-redirect.jsp</form-error-page>


        </form-login-config>

    </login-config>
...
```

Created a sample.xml file in c:\tomcat_dir\conf\Catlina\localhost which looks like this

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/sample" privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="true" antiJARLocking="true">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Context>
```

Any feedback on this issue would be appreciated.

Crossposted on [JOSSO forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/josso/forums/forum/399714/topic/4959641)

Comment: I just commented out the following line and it seems to work fine. <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/> I guess that line was trying to use some other database for user authentication whereas i wanted to use the default users from the josso-users.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate `jaas.conf` file on tomcat initialization, by adding the following parameter on VM Arguments (if you're using Eclipse):

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-josso\conf\jaas.conf
```

This file, should have the following content:

```
josso {
  org.josso.tc70.agent.jaas.SSOGatewayLoginModule required debug=true;
};
```

I'm using Tomcat managed by Eclipse IDE, so I've included the aforementioned config in Server Configuration (View Servers) / Open launch configuration / Arguments / VM Arguments.
However, if you're configuring a standalone tomcat installation, surf by %TOMCAT_HOME$/bin/ scripts e and check which jaas.conf tomcat is using and update it with the content shown above.
I hope it works for you!